# Sharepoint portal to ActiveX to WebClient back to Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webclient

Got this problem - not sure if it is possible.

User is logged into the sharepoint portal server.

1. The user opens a page (webpart) in SPS - an ActiveX is started
2. The ActiveX receives data from a docked barcode scanner.
3. The ActiveX creates a WebClient
4. The ActiveX set the credentials on the WebClient as used in point 1.)
5. The ActiveX uses WebClient.UploadFile(..)
6. In SPS an aspx/ascx page recieve the data (as the same user/session in point 1.)
7. Everybody is happy (its friday) - and goes for beer :)

it is the point 4. that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if the user credentials are the current logged in user credentials; those are sent by default when UseDefaultCredentials is set to True on the HttpWebRequest before GetResponse() is called.

If the user is supplying different credentials from the default, say NTLM negotiated credentials stored on the server, **and** the user does not select to have those credentials persisted (by selecting the "Remember my credentials" check box), then the ActiveX HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() call will throw a WebException with a message indicating the response was a 401 (unauthorized).  ActiveX's HttpWebRequest does not have access to the cached credentials used to authenticate in step (1) if they're not persisted to the Credential Manager.  If those credentials **are** persisted to the Credential Manager, the ActiveX web client will know to use the cached credentials, *as long as the target in its request is the same as the target used in the request in step (1)*; that would be the case if the host name used on both requests is the same.

Finally, if you don't have credentials in the ActiveX control, you can prompt for them using the .NET Framework [CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.  For information on these functions, and a lot more information on wrapping and using them properly from managed code see [Application Password Security](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peerchan/archive/2005/11/01/487834.aspx) from the [Peer Channel Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peerchan/) on MSDN.  Using CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials, followed by a call to [CredWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375187), you can achieve seamless password prompting from within ActiveX that has exactly the look and feel used by IE.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the authentication mechanism used - if the user logs into the page with NTLM (windows integrated), then the WebClient cannot reuse the credentials. If it's kerberos-based, you have a better chance.